# Reposition UIAlertView

Tags: ios, swift

I am want to simple a `UIAlertView` on the bottom of the screen when opening a ViewController.

Right now, I create an alert view, show it after 2 seconds and hide the alert.
However, the alert view only shows in the center of the screen.

How do I reposition it on the bottom of the screen?

Here is my code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Please Swipe To Refresh After 2 seconds", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.view.frame.origin.x = 150
alert.view.frame.origin.y = 250
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: alert.view.bounds)
indicator.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
alert.view.addSubview(indicator)
indicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false 
indicator.startAnimating()       
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't move and `UIAlertController`with its presentation style set and even if there will be a workaround don't use it. In order to achieve what you want you have different options:

- Use a simple `UIView` subclass that simply requires in the show method the view you want to use as a super view
- Create a `UIViewController` subclass and present it using a `UIPresentationController`, this could be pretty hard if you are new to iOS development
- Use one of the already available libraries on github, for instance [this](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages)

Answer (score 0):

Use `(.... , preferredStyle: .actionSheet)` in the constructor of UIAlertController